# How to submit a form to update an existing object

Tags: django, models, django-1.9

I have a model named Book that I send to an html to display data from like this:

```
books = Book.objects.all()
return render(request, 'index.html', {'books':books})
```

I then show all the information I want of the book in the front-end (which doesn't need to be shown here).

Other than showing the information of the book in the front-end I also want to introduce a small form that will have two buttons let's say "Submit" and "Decline" that will update an attribute of the Book object depending on the button clicked.

I am trying to find a good way to achieve this. My thought is to POST the entire object to a view to process later but I am not sure if is a good practice to submit an entire object from client to server as this may be affected in some way.

Comment: I like to recommend this way... When user checks or uncheck the checkbox POST data to backend for process...

Comment: @RajaSimon can you give more details on that?

Answer (score 4):

This may help you :

If you want to update database with other values related with Book's object then you can achieve it by doing the following:

```
if request.POST:
        book_form = BookForm(request.POST)

    if book_form.is_valid():

        book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
            book_form = BookForm(request.POST, instance = book)
            book_form.save()
```

It will update the existing bookObject in Database by filtering on the basis of book_id.

Comment: I don't have a form.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to send any form data if it's just an attribute you'll update. You can do something like this (I'm using uuid just as an example you can use id or whatever unique field you want):

```
# url for your update view. For example: decline
url(r'^decline/book/(?P<book_uuid>[\w\-]+)$',
    YourView.as_view(),
    name="book-decline"),

# views.py
class YourView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        book_uuid = kwargs.get('book_uuid', None)
        book = get_object_or_404(Book, uuid= book_uuid)
        # UPDATE YOUR BOOK HERE

# in your templates for each book's decline button link
<a href={% "book-decline" book.uuid %} ....>
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution seems to be ok but I was looking for a solution without depending on URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Tiny Instance provided a generic solution. If you want a more specific solution for the case of updating an object of a model by getting a form filled from the user, then Django has something inbuilt which does this for you. **FormView** is what you are looking for.

See the official documentation here -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview